# How do I place tic marks along the top borders in a 3d plot?

Tags: gnuplot

I'm making some 3D surface plots in Gnuplot and it would be very useful to have tic marks along each border of my plot. In the attached sample plot, there are no tic marks along the top left or top right horizontal borders (borders 256 and 512). In order for vertical grid lines to be drawn on the back vertical planes, I need to have tic marks on these borders. How can I achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have not found a way to solve this using the `grid` and `border`. However, there is a relatively simple workaround, which is useful only if you do not change your ranges every time you plot your data.

Basically you plot a constant surfaces on the back walls matching the line type and number and position of the grid lines in the x-y plane.

First, set up the ranges. I labeled them, because we will need the numbers later.

```
xmin=0    ; xmax = 100
ymin=0.01 ; ymax=1000
zmin=0    ; zmax=990
set xrange [xmin:xmax]
set yrange [ymin:ymax]
set zrange [zmin:zmax]
```

Setting the z axis intersection with x-y plane (ticslevel) and I guessed a view angle to visually match your example. We want to set these before `multiplot`.

```
set ticslevel 0.0
set view 60,45,1
```

Now comes the fun. For this part you have to know the number of grid lines in your x-y plane (same as number of major tics on x and y axes). We will plot the back grid walls first, so they are behind your data/function at the end. Also, I switch off the grid and border for this part, but they should exactly overlap if you leave them in.

```
set multiplot
unset grid
set border 0
```

Even though the y-axis has logarithmic scale, the grid is separated linearly (equidistant grid lines). So at this point I want linear scale on y axis. (If you `set logscale y` before this point, comment it out.) I don't want linear labels on the y-axis, because they are different on logarithmic scale, so I set the format accordingly.

```
set format y ""
set isosamples 6,9 # - set this to number of tics on y-axis,z-axis
```

Here is the only manual setting that might change when you plot on a different range. You need to set the numbers of `isosamples` to the numbers of tics on y-axis,z-axis.

To control how many lines gnuplot is going to use for each surface, we need to set both the isosamples (done above) and the ranges of dummy variables `u,v`. Notice the line type 0, which is the grid line type.
I plot my first wall at x = xmin:

```
set parametric
set urange [ymax:ymin]
set vrange [zmax:zmin]
splot xmin,u,v w lines lt 0
```

Similarly, we do the other wall at y = ymax.

```
set urange [xmin:xmax]
set vrange [zmin:zmax]
splot u,ymax,v w lines lt 0
unset parametric
```

Now that I have the walls, I can plot what you already have in the picture. Setting borders, tics, re-enable the y-axis label we disabled before, set the log-scale on y axis (now is a good time) and reset isosamples to the default values.

```
set xtics mirror
set ytics mirror
set ztics mirror
set grid ytics xtics back
set logscale y
set format y " %g"
set isosamples 10,10
```

And plot your data/function as you are used to.

```
splot 'data.txt' w lines
unset multiplot
```

And we are done....

Possible necessary modification:
I guess your x and y axes will be different from mine, since the reverse is easily achievable by something like `view 60,135,1`. This also switches x and y though. Your surfaces will then change coordinates.

Comment: wow, thanks for this detailed answer! I will get back to you when I've had a chance to try it. Looks promising...

Comment: No problem. I had fun solving this. I learned more about 3D plotting, it's quite neat, actually... I am usually stuck with 2D...

Comment: I just wanted to thank you again for this solution. I implemented it without a problem, except that I usually do have a reverse view, so had to change some x,y limits. Having the vertical grid lines there really makes some of my plots easier to read and more meaningful!

Comment: @jt_04: don't forget to vote up helpful answers and accept the one that answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try *setting tics* there using `x2tics` and `y2tics`. 
Here is the documentation of **[Xtics](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node295.html)**.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me (and yes, I did try this option before posting). As far as I can tell, both x2 and y2 are on the bottom plane of the 3d plot. I want to set tics on the horizontal borders around the top. I've tried commands such as "set xtics 256 mirror....", where 256 refers to the "top left back" border, but this doesn't work. I've also tried 512, 1024, and 2048, which are all the top horizontal borders. None of these options results in tic marks around the top.

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that this is may be ... impossible :)

Comment: gah! the horrible thought has crossed my mind, but then I think "It's gnuplot! It can do anything!". maybe not though. maybe I should figure out how to file a bug/feature request.